# After htaccess changes the css stop working as stylesheet

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mime-types

I have a weird issue with my css files.
After i changed the htaccess file to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /eventDetails\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

my css files stoped loading to ALL the pages of the website.

My public_html folder contains

- index.php
- profile.php
- css -> style.css
- js ->  owl.carousel.js
- .htaccess

With Google Chrome Developer Tools i have this error for the css files

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://something.gr/css/style.css".
```

and this error for the javascript files

```
owl.carousel.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Some images from the `Network` Tab.

WITHOUT .htaccess file

[image]

As you can see the Content-Type is text/css  .. like it should be

WITH .htaccess file

[image]

As you can see here the mime.type returns it as a text/html

What i've tried.

First.  after `<title>` html tag i've enternet

```
<base href="/">
```

Second. I've tried to change the .htaccess file to this

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
AddType application/javascript js
AddType text/css css
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /eventDetails\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

And lastly i've checked on my dedicated server `usr/local/apache/conf/`

on the mime.types file that the  `text/css css` is NOT commented the same as
`application/javascript js`

I dont know what else i should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

rewrites `/css/style.css` to `/eventDetails.php?id=css&name=style.css`.

If you want to exclude existing files from this rule, you may prefix it with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

---

You *may* also change the first rule to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)&name=(.+)
RewriteRule ^eventDetails\.php$ /%1/%2? [L,R]
```

and to prevent a redirect loop we insert at the beginning

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

You don't need this of course, if you keep the existing condition and rule against `THE_REQUEST`.

---

So the complete rules become

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)&name=(.+)
RewriteRule ^eventDetails\.php$ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: so make it out like this?  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /eventDetails\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /eventDetails.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
</IfModule>`   ??

Comment: Also refer to the documentation of [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), search for "attribute tests".

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)&name=(.+)` may cause an infinite looping error, you need to match against `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable here.

Comment: @starkeen Thank you for spotting.